# Continuous functions with orbit of period $3$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, big-list, function-and-relation-composition

> I would like to build some continuous functions $f : E \to \Bbb R$ (where $E \subset \Bbb R$ is an interval), such that
>   $$\exists x \in E,\;\;
> [f(x)≠x≠f(f(x)),\;\;
> f^3(x):= f(f(f(x)))=x]$$

I tried $f(x)=ax+b$ and $x_0=1$ and I got the condition $a^3+a^2b+ab+b=1$ which leads to $b=1-a$, so that $f(1)=a\cdot 1 + (1-a)=1$ and $x_0=1$ is a fixed point instead of being of period $3$.

(My aim is to test Sharkvosky's theorem on some examples).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $\forall x \in E$ for the second conditon only or also for the first condition. (Now you don't have it for any of the conditions, which is not useful)

Comment: My condition corresponds to a point $x$ in my interval, which has "order $3$" with respect to $f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1-2\left|x-\frac12\right|$ has the three-cycle $2/7,4/7,6/7$. This example comes from the paper "The Sharkovsky Theorem: A Natural Direct Proof", by Keith Burns and Boris Hasselblatt. A preprint is freely available online, and it's a great read.

Comment: This is a particularly nice example, because it is very easy to find sequences of any desired period: There's an $n$-cycle starting at $\frac2{2^n-1}$ for every $n\ge 3$. (And a $2$-cycle at $\frac25$, and a fixpoint at $\frac23$, just to complete the set).

Answer (score 6):

Just pull some function values out of a hat -- for example
$$ f(0) = 42 \qquad f(42)=117 \qquad f(117)=0 $$
and then do Lagrange interpolation (or for that matter linear interpolation, whatever floats your boat) between those points.

---

Your attempt with a first-degree polynomial failed because a first-degree polynomial iterated three times is *still* a first-degree polynomial, and so $f^3(x)=x$ can have only one root. Since the root of $f(x)=x$ is also a root of $f^3(x)=x$, there won't be room for any *other* ones.

But as soon as you move to quadratic polynomials there will be lots of opportunities. (Lagrange interpolation between three given points always results in a polynomial of degree $\le 2$).

Comment: Nice idea! For instance $f(x):=7/6x^2−23/6x+3$ satisfies $f(0)=3, f(3)=2, f(2)=0.$ Then by Sarkvoski's theorem I can try to find $x_n$ such that $f^n(x_n)=x_n$ and $f^k(x_n) ≠ x_n$ for all $0<k<n$, is that right? This seems incredible to me!